# Specify Heap Size in Perl Script for Java Code

Tags: java, perl, cygwin, heap-memory

The Java project I am working on needs to be tested for 1800 configurations. I have created a perl script for this and running it on cygwin.

Some of these configurations require more heap space than the default available space. How can I specify the heap size in perl script?

I have tried these commands but they didn't work.

```
system('java -Xmx512m');
system('java -xmx1g -xms512m');
system("java -Xmx512m -jar foo.jar');
```

Comment: I don't believe that your answer is cygwin related.

Comment: How did they "not work"?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I got an error message `Failed to load Main-class manifest attribute from foo.jar` and then program used default heap size

Answer (score 3):

try the following:

```
system('<full path to java>/java -xms512m -xmx1024m -cp <full classpath> -jar <full path to your jar>/foo.jar')
```

Answer (score 2):

If possible, I always try to use the `system PROGRAM, LIST` way, and with complete paths, if I know them.